# ASP.NET MVC - controller action method from console application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I want to have an console application that I would use to render the output to a file.

Pseudocode:

```
ComponentBaseController controller = new ComponentBaseController();
SaveToFile("output.html", controller.Result);
```

I am not using real code here since I have tried different approaches, but nothing gets me near.

The closest I got using [Tip # 25 from Stephen Walther](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/07/26/asp-net-mvc-tip-25-unit-test-your-views-without-a-web-server.aspx), is this:

```
ComponentBaseController controller = new ComponentBaseController();

RouteData routeData = new RouteData();
routeData.Values.Add("controller", "ComponentBase");

var fakeContext = new FakeControllerContext(controller, routeData);

var result = controller.Details("klasta7") as PartialViewResult;
result.ExecuteResult(fakeContext);
Console.Write(fakeContext.HttpContext.Response.ToString());
```

This throws an System.InvalidOperationException that the partial view could not be found. Tried different locations for Views folder, but no luck.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not one to try to recommend something other than what you're asking to do, but I agree with Wyatt, the goal seems a little on the sticky side, and at best is going to create some code smell.  If you simply need to save the rendered output to a file, I think it'd be easier to have an app service that gets called when you need to do the save, likely from the controller.  In that event, you'd have access to a current HttpContext, Routes, etc.

If it's a separate app altogether (the console app exists on it's own), what about setting up a service from within the web app that has a method the console app could call to retrieve the rendered output?

Comment: mannish, would that service be able to call the controller action directly then? That's also a viable solution for me. Thanks!

Comment: Even if this is not what I was looking for, I'll mark this as an answer. I did it this way in the end since I didn't want to lose more time on this task.

Answer (score 0):

It is going to be tricky to get stuff to render without hosting the app in something as there is no HttpContext, etc.

Now, using WebRequest to grab pages from a running version of the app and dumping them to disk is a bit more doable.

Finally, this sounds a bit FUBAR. What is the goal of this operation?

Comment: Hi Wyatt, here's the goal (although it doesn't matter really).

I have some partial views that should be rendered to a file and the transferred to another server via ftp. 

So I need a way to produce HTML, but since I already have my partial views, don't want to duplicate code.

I don't see how it FUBAR really. If you think about how MVC should be easily testable and all that, how come it's so hard to reproduce the final result of a controller method - HTML?